# How to make a UILabel appear on screen when the an image isn't being tracked, and disappear when an image is being tracked

Tags: swift, uilabel, augmented-reality, arkit, image-recognition

I am making an image recognition app using ARKit, where a user will point the camera at a few different images in a space, and videos will play over those images. I have created UILabel with messages in order to provide instructions to the user. When the user first opens the app, i want to display a message to them telling them to point the camera at the image. Whenever the image is being tracked by the camera, I want the UILabel to disappear.

In my code, I gotten it to where I can make the Label disappear when an image is tracked, but I can't get it to reappear once I am not tracking the image anymore.

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: 
ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        let node = SCNNode()

        //Show video overlayed to image
        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor{
            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.messageView?.isHidden = 
true }
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: 
imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: 
imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

            //Create Plane
            switch imageAnchor.referenceImage.name!{
            case "slaveAuction":
                //Set AVPlayer as the planes texture and play
                plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = 
self.slaveAuction
                self.slaveAuction.play()
            case "columbus":
                plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = 
self.columbus
                self.columbus.play()
            case "isabellasCourt":
                plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = 
self.isabellasCourt
                self.isabellasCourt.play()
            case "hawksbell":
                plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = 
self.hawksbell
                self.hawksbell.play()
            default:
                print("Images not found")
            }

            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

            // Rotate the plane to match the anchor
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

            // Add plane node to parent
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        }

        return node
    }

}
```

I need help making the message view appear when I am not tracking the image.

Answer (score 0):

Make your planeNode class variable. And check if your node is visible every frame.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    if let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView, planeNode != nil {
        let isMaybeVisible = sceneView.isNode(planeNode, insideFrustumOf: pointOfView)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if isMaybeVisible{
                self.messageView.isHidden = true
            }else{
                self.messageView.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And see [isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522647-isnode)